# four text divs next to image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put four divs with text to the right of an image. So basically get 2 divs right next to each other and then 2 more divs underneath the first 2 divs where i want to put in text.  Making all of this responsive would also be nice but not necessary.

Still learning so im not sure what to try and what not to try but ive mostly tried playing around with flexbox lines but none of them do what im trying to achieve, ive tried floating them into their positions but that doesnt work either.

```css
.breadbody {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.breadpic {
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 1000px;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

.pictext {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 500px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.pictext2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 500px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.pictext3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: flex-end;
  max-height: 500px;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}

.pictext4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: flex-end;
  max-height: 500px;
  border: 5px solid aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadbody">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" alt="example" class="breadpic">
  <div class="pictext">
    <div>
      <h3> are like examples thats why i do examples egg</h3>
    </div>
    <div>examples are like examples thats why i do examples eggexamples are like examples thats why i do examples egg</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pictext2">
    <div>
      <h3>here and there and thats why we do example</h3>
    </div>
    <div>examples are like examples thats why i do examples eggexamples are like examples thats why i do examples egg</div>
  </div>enter image description here
  <div class="pictext3">
    <div>
      <h3>here and there and thats why we do example</h3>
    </div>
    <div>examples are like examples thats why i do examples egg but i dont do any more exampling</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pictext4">
    <div>
      <h3>example text</h3>
    </div>
    <div>example text here and here and there and thats why we do example</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can we alter a bit your `HTML` structure (and the `CSS` as well) ?

Comment: sure thing you can

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved easily with CSS-Grid. Create a 3 columns grid and let the image span 2 rows:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
}

img {
  grid-row: span 2;
}


/* for visualization purpose */
div {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for, could you however explain what the 'grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr 1fr; ' means, more specifically the 'min-content 1fr 1fr; ' as im not sure how to understand it. Thanks a bunch for the help and ill need to look more into CSS-Grid.

Comment: this creates 3 columns. 1st: only as wide as needed, and the other 2 each 1 fraction of the remaining space.

Comment: okay i understand it now, thanks a bunch, youve been a tremendous help